# Faster JOIN using LIKE

Tags: mysql, query-performance, join, query, mariadb-10.5

I have a simple tag table as

```
CREATE TABLE Tags
(
TagID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Tag varchar(255),
ParentID int(11) unsigned,
Parent enum('Yes', 'No'),
UNIQUE INDEX(Tag),
INDEX(ParentID),
INDEX(Parent),
PRIMARY KEY(TagID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

I want to set the `ParentID` for tags containing other tags. For example,

```
TagID    Tag          ParentID   Parent
1        work         NULL       Yes
2        works        1          No
3        best works   1          No
4        my work      1          No
```

The base tag is given as `Parent enum('Yes', 'No')`. I came up with the query

```
UPDATE Tags a JOIN Tags b 
    ON a.Tag LIKE CONCAT('%', b.Tag, '%')
    AND a.ParentID IS NULL AND b.ParentID IS NULL
    AND a.Parent='No' AND b.ParentID='Yes'
SET a.ParentID=b.TagID
```

but it is very slow. Is there any alternative to do so?

Comment: This idea looks like incorrect. It is possible that some tag contains 2 separate tags as substrings (which are not related) - your scheme does not take this situation into account and does not allow to store such relation. Your scheme is by fact M:N relation.

Comment: Your query is complete cartesian by an expression - i.e. fullscan by each table copy. It MUST be slow. I recommend you to gather the words list (parse each tag to separate words, build complete words list, and at the same time store words list per tag. Then set the relation between separate words (length(word1) < length(word2) and substring(word2, length(word1)) = word1). Finally build the relation between tags.

Comment: Why have the `Parent` column?  `ParentID IS NULL` provides the same info (at least for your sample data).

Comment: What results do you want for that data?

Comment: @RickJames `Parent` is set separately. Without setting `Parent` as a guiding column, the ParentID of *best works* can be either `1` or `2`. The intended result is the 3rd column in the sample data.